# Reading Meggilah for women

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, women, halacha

What is the Process if you are Laining Meggilah for women only:
Who makes the Bracha? Before and  after? Can a person who has already heard be yotzeh the Women? Does it make a difference if it is Multiple women or one?

Answer (score 5):

See: “Women’s Megillah Reading,” Aryeh A. Frimer, In “Traditions and Celebrations for the Bat Mitzvah,” Ora Wiskind Elper, Editor; Urim Publications: Jerusalem, 2003; pp. 281-304. PDF file available online at: http://mj.bu.edu/rsrc/MailJewish/MjReaderContributions/WomensMegillaReadingRev3.doc; HTML files available at http://www.lookstein.org/articles/women_megilla_reading.htm and http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimer2.htm.

Comment: Aryeh Frimer, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for pointing out your work on this subject! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking login/register, above.

Comment: Would it be possible to summarize that part of that text that answers this question, per the advice at http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/04/guidelines-referring-and-quoting.html?

Answer (score 2):

Per the Magain Avrohom 585:3 if the one reading the Megila has already heard the Megila and fulfilled the mitzvah, it is advisable that those listening should say the Bracha "Lishmoah Megila" themselves rather than have the reader say the blessing.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement, not supplant, [R'Gershon Gold's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6425), no one says a *b'racha* after a reading for women. (Source: *Rama* 692:1, q.v.)

Comment: The paper referred to in R'Aryeh Frimer's answer, http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6501, if I understand it correctly, quotes some who say that my answer is incorrect (and some who say it's correct). Nonetheless, I believe my answer is standard practice. As always, for practical _halacha_, CYLOR.

Comment: I don't think you have a good source for your claim in this answer given the Rama's comments to 690:18

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes, see my previous comment.

Comment: I thought you were sayingthere that others disagree with the rama (which would be true). I'm saying you haven't even interpreted the rama correctly.